# How can I capture validation errors in a new Backbone.Model during instantiation?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It is easy to bind to the 'error' event of an existing model, but what is the best way to determine if a new model is valid?

```
Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(attributes) {
    if(attributes.weight == null || attributes.weight <=0) {
      return 'Weight must be a non-negative integer';
    }
    return '';
  }
});

Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Car
});

var cars = new Cars();
cars.add({'weight': -5}); //Invalid model. How do I capture the error from the validate function?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Validation logic can be triggered explicitly by calling the `validate` method of your model.  This will not, however, cause an `error` event to be triggered.  You can trigger an error event manually for a model by calling the `trigger` method.

One way to achieve your desired behavior is to manually trigger the event in your initialization method:

```
Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    var error = this.validate(this.attributes);
    if (error) {
      this.trigger('error', this, error);
    }
  },
  validate: function(attributes) {
    if(attributes.weight == null || attributes.weight <=0) {
      return 'Weight must be a non-negative integer';
    }
    return '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. Sometimes the Backbone docs aren't great at fleshing out the details.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure that all events on all models in a collection will be passed to and triggered by the collection as well. So you should be able to listen to the `error` event on the collection:

```
var cars = new Cars();
cars.bind('error', function() {
    console.log('Model not valid!')
})
cars.add({'weight': -5});
```

**Edit**: Nope, this works for setting properties on existing models, but not on model creation. Ugh - it looks like there's no way to listen for this without overriding some part of the Backbone code. Models don't perform validation when they're initialized:

```
var car = new Car({weight: -5});
console.log(car.get('weight')); // no error, logs -5
```

And while `collection.add()` does perform validation, it fails silently.

If you use `collection.create()` instead of `collection.add()`, you can check, since `.create()` will return `false` on failure. But this will try to create the model on the server, which might not be what you want.

So, I think the only way to do this is to override `collection._prepareModel` and trigger a custom event, like this:

```
Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Car,
  _prepareModel: function(model, options) {
      model = Backbone.Collection.prototype._prepareModel.call(this, model, options);
      if (!model) this.trigger('error:validation');
      return model;
  }
});

var cars = new Cars();
cars.bind('error:validation', function() {
    console.log('Model not valid!')
});
cars.add({'weight': -5}); // logs: 'Model not valid!'
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/f44qk/1/

Answer (score 1):

i encountered problem like it

my solution

```
...

var handler = function(model, error, context) {}

try {
  cars.add({}, { error: handler })
} catch (e) { }        

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.collection.fetch({
    validate: true
});
```