# How do you create a backbone model that might be invalid upon creation?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a backbone model using:

```
var newUser = new App.User({
    name: $('input[name=new_user_name]').val(),
    email: $('input[name=new_user_email]').val()
  });
```

with the following validation:

```
App.User = Backbone.Model.extend({

  validate: function(attrs) {
    errors = [];
    if (_.isEmpty(attrs.name)) {
      errors.push("Name can't be blank");
    }
    if (_.isEmpty(attrs.email)) {
      errors.push("Email can't be blank");
    }

    return _.any(errors) ? errors : null;
  },
...
});
```

However, when the textbox values are empty, the model can't be created because the validations fail.

Is there a way to create a model and run `isValid()` to check the values are correct? Or is there some other way to run validations before the model is created?

From the [backbone model creation code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-26), it appears it throws the exception `Error("Can't create an invalid model")` upon failing validation, but would it be possible to check validations before hand?

Comment: I'm new to backbone, but it looks to me like it is passing in the option `silent:true` to the `set` method, and the set method passes that option to validate, and a truthy silent property bypasses validation: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-55

Comment: I believe the {silent:true} is only for suppressing the events triggered by changing the model. So if I model.set({name:'orange'},{silent:true}); it will prevent the model change event from triggering and as a result, any listeners that would react to this model's change event will not execute. This is handy if you had a View that was bound to the model change and reflected the change accordingly. E.g. model.bind('change', this.onChange, this)

Answer (score 3):

You can create unvalid model with `silent: true`, but in this way collection don`t trow event 'add'. But you can sent default option to function add and catch this option in validate()

```
collection.add({option:'unvalid_value'}, {validation: false});
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(attributes, options){
    if (options.validation === false)
      return;
    //Validation code
    //.....       
  }
});
```

This way you can create model with invalid hash)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to create a user model and that model gets populated with attributes based on some form input.

The way you have it set up now, to me doesn't seem very backbone-y.

```
var newUser = new App.User({
    name: $('input[name=new_user_name]').val(),
    email: $('input[name=new_user_email]').val()
});
```

To me it feels like you're mixing up stuff that happens in your views with your model which is the object it should represent. I would probably create a basic blank Model first, then a View that compliments this model and pass the model in.

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults: {
        name: undefined,
        email: undefined
    }
)};

UserView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    events: {
        // like click on submit link, etc.
        'click #submitButton': 'onSubmit'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.user = this.model;
    },
    onSubmit: function() {
        // run some validation on form inputs, ex. look for blanks, then...
        if ( /* validation passes */ ) {
            var nameEntered = $('input[name=new_user_name]').val();
            var emailEntered = $('input[name=new_user_email]').val();
            this.user.set({name:nameEntered, email:nameEntered});
        }
    }
});

// Do it!
var newUser = new User();
var newUserView = new UserView({model:newUser});
```

One great way to validate the form INPUT rather than than the Model attributes is to use jquerytools validator. It works with HTML5 attributes such as pattern=regex and type=email and makes it super easy.

Comment: I do do something similar, where my model is declared in a view, but I guess I wanted to use my validations in the backbone model in my backbone view as well ie, where you have "/* validation passes */"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an Invalid model in backbone.

If you are creating a model and passing values to the constructor the no validation will be done.

If you are adding models to a collection via fetch then invalid data will cause the model validation to fail and the model will not be added to the collection. This should trigger the `error` event so you should be listening for it in case your server is providing invalid data back.

If you want to make a model but make sure the data is valid you must:

```
var mymodel = new MyModel();
mymodel.set(attrs);
```

Even if you try to pass `{silent: false}` during model instantation backbone will override it since it will not let you create an invalid model and does not throw errors. (which we arent discussing here)

You can see this by looking at the source, but also look at this [github ticket](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1049)

Comment: Also not part of my answer but I've written a model validation mixin for backbone. http://github.com/toddself/Backbone.Validator

Comment: Good point on how the model validation might come in handy. In this question, server side and fetch concepts aren't explicitly mentioned but I think this answer shows the other side of a complete backbone based project. I think the idea of model validation vs input validation is an important one.

Comment: The details of the question go into the server aspects but the subject is directly answered by this. Figure that people are going to come here looking for an answer for that basic question as well. Plus you can use model validation to provide input validation by listening to the errr messages. A little round about but possible.

Comment: The problem with doing "var newUser = new App.User();" is that the validations check for empty name and email, so it will fail on this line. Also if it fails on creation, then I can't attach error handlers seeing as the object isn't created.

Comment: @zlog But it won't fail. Read that github comment between myself and Jeremy. Very specifically backbone will ALWAYS return a valid model from `new`. Validation is not called then. Which is why you should do the code in my answer. This is how to make Model and ensure data is valid. (it's how the collection does it)